# Get min and max group value from multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have multi dimensional array like this

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-05
            [price] => 40800.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-05
            [price] => 42699.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-11-07
            [price] => 43500.00
        )

)
```

How i can get the value of **price** and **date** where **price is minimum** and where **price is maximum** in php?

Comment: Where did the array come from?

Comment: first write code and show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for maximum:

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($memo, $el) {
  if($memo[0] < $el['price']) {
    $memo = array($el['price'], $el);
  }
  return $memo;
}, array(0, null));

echo $result[1]; // contains the maximal element
```

I guess it’s clear enough how to get the minimal value.

On the other hand, you may [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) an array and then get first and last values:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { 
  return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? 
      -1 : (int) !($a['price'] === $b['price']); 
});
```

Now you have a sorted by price array.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $arr=array(
      array
            (
                'date' => 2014-11-05,
                'price' => 40800.00
            ),

         array
            (
                'date' => 2014-11-05,
                'price' => 42699.00
            )
    ,
         array
            (
                'date' => 2014-11-07,
                'price' => 43500.00
            )

    );
        $temp=0;
        foreach($arr as $person) {
            $p=$person['price'];
            if($temp<$p)
              $temp=$p;

        }
        echo 'Max price: '. $temp;

         $t=$arr[0]['price'];
        foreach($arr as $person) {
           $p=$person['price'];
             if($t>$p)
             $t=$p;

           }
echo "Min price: ".$t;
```